# Convert PostScript to PDF using user interface?

Tags: gui, pdf, postscript

I own small printshop and looking forward to work in linux OS. Now im trying Ubuntu 12.04 on my old workstation. But the biggest problem i found i cant convert PostScript files to PDF format using user interface. I just got no time to write all of the specs for every .pdf file in terminal using Ghostscript ps2pdf.
Isnt out there anything like Acrobat Distiller for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Try CUPS-PDF.

> CUPS-PDF is designed to produce PDF files in a heterogeneous network
>   by providing a PDF printer on the central fileserver. It is available
>   under the GPL and is packaged for many different distributions or can
>   be built directly out of the source files.

To install cups-pdf, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```

Add a new printer.  Follow the screens below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now you should be able to print to pdf by selecting the newly setup printer.

Also take a look at [AbiWord](http://www.abisource.com/)

<sup>Source:[CUPS-PDF](http://www.cups-pdf.de/)</sup>